# Value not displayed when returned as array

Tags: ruby

I have this piece of code

```
class Test
  def self.testme(a, b)
    @arr = [@x, @y]
    if (a == 0)
      if (b == 0)
        return nil
      else
        @x = a * b
        return @arr[0]
      end
    end
    ...# @y needed in other part below
  end
end
```

and want to return the array with the corresponding value (either result in `@x` or `@y`) so that the result is `[12]` when `3` and `4` are input.

But I get `nil` when I use `return @arr[0]`, or `[nil]` when using `return @arr[0,1]`. When I return just `@arr` the result is something like `[12, nil]` even though there should be something in `@y`

Returning only `@x` or `@y` works, but doesn't solve my problem. How can I make this work?

Comment: Your question would be a lot easier to solve if you posted the prompt. In other words, what functionality are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd be cautious about using instance variables like this in the context of the class. Only persist what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
@arr = [@x, @y]
```

is not doing quite what you think it does. It does not create an `Array` with *maintained* references to the variables `@x`, `@y`. Instead it creates an `Array` containing the *current* values of `@x` and `@y`. (See footnote)

Therefore, when you change the object that `@x` or `@y` point to, as in the line `@x = a * b`, this does not affect `@arr`.

The simple fix, if you want to return an array containing the final values of `@x` and `@y`, is to construct and return that array at the end, in order to return it. You probably don't need `@arr` at all in order to do that.

Just

```
return [@x, @y]
```

would do that. If that is at the very end of your method, then it is Ruby convention to omit the `return` and just have

```
[@x, @y]
```

If for some reason, you really do need to maintain the `@arr` variable and `return @arr[0]` as per your example, then you will need to set `@arr` just before you return it e.g.

```
  else
    @x = a * b
    @arr = [@x, @y]
    return @arr[0]
  end
```

or even

```
  else
    @arr = [a * b, @y]
    return @arr[0]
  end
```

if `@x` is supposed to be internal to the method (in which case, BTW, you would be better off calling it just `x` if it needs to hold some temporary working values)

---

Footnote: In Ruby it is important to track the distinction between variables and the objects they point to. It is because you *re-assign* the variable `@x` that you see the results that you do. When you use more complex objects, such as Strings or Arrays, and modify them *in place* (e.g. for a `String` use `@x.gsub!( /foo/, 'bar' )`) then you may be able to use the technique of setting up the return structure at the beginning and adjusting it.

Comment: Oh, yes, that does it. Thank you for your explanation.